# what is the byte structuture of ffmpeg rawvideo file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, format, byte

after creating a file using `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb0 out.raw`
I want to open `out.raw` file in binary and read some pixels in my C code
so what is the byte structuture or format of that `out.raw` file?
for example the byte structure or format of `sound.wav` file is https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265163681/figure/fig1/AS:651531422560256@1532348604142/The-structure-of-wav-file-format.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no metadata or container control structure. Rawvideo is simply a linear dump of raw payload, frame by frame.

For `-vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt $PIX_FMT`, consult the layout of $PIX_FMT under `av_pix_fmt_descriptors[AV_PIX_FMT_NB]` in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/pixdesc.c. See data structure in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/pixdesc.h